# WS-Security policy and saml2 token, Error in signature with a custom token

Tags: java, web-services, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have a problem with a security scenario I'm trying to implement.
Actually I think it's a quite common scenario, given that it's in the [oasis examples](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/security-policy/examples/ws-sp-usecases-examples.html#_Toc274723261): a saml2 token over a ssl client authenticated connection.

The policy I'm using is this:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MyX509" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>

            <sp:TransportBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="true"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>

            <sp:SignedEndorsingSupportingTokens>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:IssuedToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <sp:Issuer>
                            <Address xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts</Address>
                        </sp:Issuer>
                        <sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
                            <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
                            <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/SymmetricKey</t:KeyType>
                            <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
                            <t:Claims Dialect="http://wso2.org/claims" xmlns:ic="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity">
                                <ic:ClaimType Uri="http://wso2.org/claims/givenname" />
                            </t:Claims>
                        </sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                    </sp:IssuedToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedEndorsingSupportingTokens>

            <rampart:RampartConfig xmlns:rampart="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
                <rampart:encryptionUser>useReqSigCert</rampart:encryptionUser>
                <rampart:timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds>true</rampart:timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds>
                <rampart:timestampTTL>300</rampart:timestampTTL>
                <rampart:timestampMaxSkew>300</rampart:timestampMaxSkew>
                <rampart:tokenStoreClass>org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore</rampart:tokenStoreClass>
                <rampart:nonceLifeTime>300</rampart:nonceLifeTime>
            </rampart:RampartConfig>

        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

I'm using WSO2 identity server as STS and WSO2 esb as the PEP.
My problem is at client level: after I retrieve the saml token from IS, axis2 gets an exception when building the request; the exception occurs before the request is sent. So I assume there's some problem with my policy.
This is the exception:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error in signature with a custom token
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:427)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at samples.services.StockQuoteProxyStub.getQuote(StockQuoteProxyStub.java:259)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.samples.sts.Client.run(Client.java:203)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.samples.sts.Client.main(Client.java:91)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Error in signature with a custom token
    at org.apache.rampart.builder.TransportBindingBuilder.doIssuedTokenSignature(TransportBindingBuilder.java:462)
    at org.apache.rampart.builder.TransportBindingBuilder.build(TransportBindingBuilder.java:119)
    at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:140)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Signature creation failed
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:558)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:478)
    at org.apache.rampart.builder.TransportBindingBuilder.doIssuedTokenSignature(TransportBindingBuilder.java:451)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: list of references must contain at least one entry
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignedInfo.<init>(DOMSignedInfo.java:70)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignedInfo.<init>(DOMSignedInfo.java:99)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.newSignedInfo(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:100)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.newSignedInfo(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:507)
    ... 15 more
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed a difference in my transport binding policy from the oasis example one. The policy now is:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MyX509" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>

            <sp:TransportBinding>
  <wsp:Policy>
    <sp:TransportToken>
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:HttpsToken>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:RequireClientCertificate/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:HttpsToken>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:TransportToken>
    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:Basic256 />
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
    <sp:Layout>
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:Strict />
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:Layout>
    <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
  </wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportBinding>

            <sp:SignedEndorsingSupportingTokens>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:IssuedToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <sp:Issuer>
                            <Address xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts</Address>
                        </sp:Issuer>
                        <sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
                            <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
                            <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/SymmetricKey</t:KeyType>
                            <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
                            <t:Claims Dialect="http://wso2.org/claims" xmlns:ic="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity">
                                <ic:ClaimType Uri="http://wso2.org/claims/givenname" />
                            </t:Claims>
                        </sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                    </sp:IssuedToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedEndorsingSupportingTokens>

            <rampart:RampartConfig xmlns:rampart="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
                <rampart:encryptionUser>useReqSigCert</rampart:encryptionUser>
                <rampart:timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds>true</rampart:timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds>
                <rampart:timestampTTL>300</rampart:timestampTTL>
                <rampart:timestampMaxSkew>300</rampart:timestampMaxSkew>
                <rampart:tokenStoreClass>org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore</rampart:tokenStoreClass>
                <rampart:nonceLifeTime>300</rampart:nonceLifeTime>
            </rampart:RampartConfig>

        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

now I can send the request, but get an exception in the esb:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:10:20,673] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.token.SecurityTokenReference.getKeyIdentifier(SecurityTokenReference.java:446)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleEncryptedKey(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:250)
    at org.apache.ws.security.saml.SAML2Util.getSAML2KeyInfo(SAML2Util.java:244)
    at org.apache.ws.security.saml.SAML2Util.getSAML2KeyInfo(SAML2Util.java:148)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:334)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:124)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:332)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:214)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

May be a keystores issue?

**UPDATE2**

I modified again the policy, trying to give rampart some configuration about keystore (Actually I don't know what I'm doing :) )

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MyX509"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>

            <sp:TransportBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireClientCertificate />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:HttpsToken>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256 />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>

            <sp:SignedEndorsingSupportingTokens>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:IssuedToken
                        sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <sp:Issuer>
                            <Address xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts
                            </Address>
                        </sp:Issuer>
                        <sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate
                            xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
                            <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
                            <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/SymmetricKey
                            </t:KeyType>
                            <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
                            <t:Claims Dialect="http://wso2.org/claims"
                                xmlns:ic="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity">
                                <ic:ClaimType Uri="http://wso2.org/claims/givenname" />
                            </t:Claims>
                        </sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                    </sp:IssuedToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedEndorsingSupportingTokens>

            <rampart:RampartConfig xmlns:rampart="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
                <rampart:encryptionUser>useReqSigCert</rampart:encryptionUser>
                <rampart:timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds>true
                </rampart:timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds>
                <rampart:timestampTTL>300</rampart:timestampTTL>
                <rampart:timestampMaxSkew>300</rampart:timestampMaxSkew>
                <rampart:tokenStoreClass>org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore
                </rampart:tokenStoreClass>
                <rampart:nonceLifeTime>300</rampart:nonceLifeTime>
                <rampart:encryptionCrypto>
                    <rampart:crypto provider="org.wso2.carbon.security.util.ServerCrypto"
                        cryptoKey="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.privatestore">
                        <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.alias">server</rampart:property>
                        <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.privatestore">server.jks
                        </rampart:property>
                        <rampart:property name="org.wso2.stratos.tenant.id">-1234</rampart:property>
                        <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.truststores">server.jks,
                        </rampart:property>
                        <rampart:property name="rampart.config.user">server</rampart:property>
                    </rampart:crypto>
                </rampart:encryptionCrypto>
                <rampart:signatureCrypto>
                    <rampart:crypto provider="org.wso2.carbon.security.util.ServerCrypto"
                        cryptoKey="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.privatestore">
                        <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.alias">server</rampart:property>
                        <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.privatestore">server.jks
                        </rampart:property>
                        <rampart:property name="org.wso2.stratos.tenant.id">-1234</rampart:property>
                        <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.truststores">server.jks,
                        </rampart:property>
                        <rampart:property name="rampart.config.user">server</rampart:property>
                    </rampart:crypto>
                </rampart:signatureCrypto>
            </rampart:RampartConfig>

        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

now I get a brand new exception:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:44:51,583] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} -  Error processing POST request for : /services/StockQuoteProxy.StockQuoteProxyHttpsSoap12Endpoint {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The signature or decryption was invalid; nested exception is: 
    java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:186)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:95)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid; nested exception is: 
    java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleEncryptedKey(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:370)
    at org.apache.ws.security.saml.SAML2Util.getSAML2KeyInfo(SAML2Util.java:244)
    at org.apache.ws.security.saml.SAML2Util.getSAML2KeyInfo(SAML2Util.java:148)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:334)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:124)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:332)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:214)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:311)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:121)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:763)
    at org.wso2.carbon.security.util.ServerCrypto.getPrivateKey(ServerCrypto.java:247)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleEncryptedKey(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:368)
    ... 18 more
```

the server.jks content, used also in axis2.xml configuration is:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 4 entries

Alias name: client
Creation date: 27-Oct-2014
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=Client, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Issuer: CN=Exprivia Certification Authority, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Serial number: 2
Valid from: Mon Oct 27 15:50:03 CET 2014 until: Sat Aug 11 16:50:03 CEST 2288
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  F5:5E:E1:2D:AF:0A:BE:D2:62:8C:90:61:BD:6B:60:5C
     SHA1: B4:47:78:08:14:FC:79:86:3F:01:32:85:4C:1F:97:67:9E:0F:E3:4F
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 1


*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: wso2carbon
Creation date: 31-Oct-2014
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=localhost, O=WSO2, L=Mountain View, ST=CA, C=US
Issuer: CN=localhost, O=WSO2, L=Mountain View, ST=CA, C=US
Serial number: 4b7e3782
Valid from: Fri Feb 19 08:02:26 CET 2010 until: Tue Feb 13 08:02:26 CET 2035
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  02:FB:AA:5F:20:64:49:4A:27:29:55:71:83:F7:46:CD
     SHA1: 6B:F8:E1:36:EB:36:D4:A5:6E:A0:5C:7A:E4:B9:A4:5B:63:BF:97:5D
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: cacert
Creation date: 27-Oct-2014
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=Exprivia Certification Authority, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Issuer: CN=Exprivia Certification Authority, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Serial number: d072ec58b3585976
Valid from: Mon Oct 27 15:50:03 CET 2014 until: Sat Aug 11 16:50:03 CEST 2288
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  FA:4F:7C:C5:6A:43:5B:25:7C:3E:5B:E5:76:39:82:44
     SHA1: 20:F3:C0:3F:28:A1:2E:9B:82:81:1A:08:D7:99:02:A3:87:BD:23:2F
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 87 3F E9 0F 6E F0 2D CD   7C 11 9D DC 54 F8 70 B6  .?..n.-.....T.p.
0010: CA 80 FE DD                                        ....
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 87 3F E9 0F 6E F0 2D CD   7C 11 9D DC 54 F8 70 B6  .?..n.-.....T.p.
0010: CA 80 FE DD                                        ....
]

]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: server
Creation date: 27-Oct-2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=10.0.3.124, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Issuer: CN=Exprivia Certification Authority, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Serial number: 1
Valid from: Mon Oct 27 15:50:03 CET 2014 until: Sat Aug 11 16:50:03 CEST 2288
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  2B:67:3A:03:1D:33:3B:C4:49:EE:4C:EA:17:74:E0:10
     SHA1: 41:92:2A:E3:8E:DE:FE:0A:3D:3D:CF:F1:10:02:02:74:45:3A:6B:8E
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  IPAddress: 10.0.3.124
]



*******************************************
*******************************************
```

Any clue?

Thanks, Paolo

Answer (score 0):

The last issue was somehow related to the way I generated my keystores, replacing those with wso2carbon.jks solved the problem.